# PHP FastCGI Process Manager (FPM) on IIS

Tags: php, iis, php-fpm, fastcgi, iis-8.5

Is there a way to enable fpm-fcgi sapi on IIS? I'm aware that the default SAPI for PHP on IIS is cgi-fcgi.

Comment: I believe all you need to learn is discussed already in https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php